# how to obfuscate my dll using Dotfuscator and Analytics Community Edition[Version:5.5.4521.29298]?

Tags: dotfuscator

Using Dotfuscator and Community Edition , i am trying to obfuscate my dll, with the following procedures,
Using Add Input->added my dll .
In Inputs Tab->Properties->Disabled all the properties except Honor instrumentation attributes and Strip instrumentation attributes, though its enabled by default.
In Properties->Build Settings->Global obfuscation settings->enabled the smart obfuscation.
In Analytics  tab->Options->Analytics configuration disabled the send shelf life notification messages and send tamper alert messages.
In Renaming tab->Built In Rules->availale rules disabled the Fields with accessedthroughpropertyattribute and window workflow activites and crystalreportclass objects.
remaining all in enabled state.

Remaining options like control flow, string ecryption are not highlighted though its not free to user

Using the above steps i build the dll. i got new dll, i checked whether obfuscated happened correctly or not, so using .Net Reflector 8.0 software i try to get my original source code,**some part of class files in dll are obfuscated properly i.e.,class names,method names,field name changed properly,but few class names doesn't changed, i don't know what is the probelm, did i missed any other options to choose? how can i make my dll more obfuscate using dotfuscator community edition 5.5.45**
Any Ideas?

Comment: Do you hvae Library Mode turned on? If so, you may consider turning it off and excluding any public methods needed manually, or you might try making less classes public that don't need to be

Comment: Already my Library Mode is turned off state only(I disabled the Library mode option in properties),my class names,methode names,variable names inside the dll are changed,but few of my classnames doesn't changed,but inside that class names ,method names are changed perfectly,i want remaining class names to be change. how it is possible?